# PROJ.4 cs2cs is too slow. Alternative?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj, cs2cs

I use PROJ.4 `cs2cs` to convert data from a Lambert Conformal Conic to a geodetic coordinate (NAD83) or vice versa. In my application, sometimes I need to convert a lot of data. Because I call `cs2cs` with subprocess.Popen() and parse result in python, input/output overhead becomes too big for a large data set.

Is there an faster alternative to cs2cs or a way to make calling `cs2cs` in python faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is [Pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj). Transforms lists of coordinates in a single call, and since it's a C extension module that uses PROJ.4, the same results as `cs2cs` but at C speed.

Comment: Using [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) increased the speed by 11,000 times faster. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Mark the question answered :)